# .test in javascript not working as per expectation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have create a small plugin that customize select menu. I have to implement search functionality in that dropdown. However I have add the functionality but sometimes it is not giving correct result for example. if you type 'a' in input box then it should display result as given below

[image]

but my plugin is giving result below. It is also replacing uppercase letter with lowercase.
I am trying to solve this but could not getting any idea to fix it. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkjarLes/)

[image]

```
searchItem: function () {
    var patt = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi')
    var val = this.value;
    $('#options li').each(function () {

        if (!patt.test($(this).text())) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            apply.highlight.call(this, val);
        }
    });

    $('#options h2').each(function () {
        if (!patt.test($('label', this).text())) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            apply.highlight.call(this, val)
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind fixing the typo in your code and indenting it :)

Comment: You want to use the matched text, not the value typed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the unmatched items is that you are using the test method of the same `RegExp` object for multiple elements.

But [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Description) will move the starting position for each match (*it is for matching subsequent matches on the same string*)

So you should create a new RegExp object for each element. (*or use the `.match()` and check its length*)

```
searchItem: function () {
        var pattValue = this.value;
        var val = this.value;
        $('#options li').each(function () {
            var patt = new RegExp(pattValue, 'gi');
            if (!patt.test($(this).text())) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                apply.highlight.call(this, val);
            }
        });

        $('#options h2').each(function () {
            var patt = new RegExp(pattValue, 'gi');
            if (!patt.test($('label', this).text())) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                apply.highlight.call(this, val);
            }
        });
    }
```

---

For the replacing of the chars to the one you inputted use the matched text instead of the user submitted one, you need to create a group in the RegExp and use that capture to replace the match

```
    highlight: function (val) {
        var nn = new RegExp('(' + (val||'^$') + ')', 'gi');
        var txt = $(this).find('label').text();
        txt = txt.replace(nn, "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");
        $('label', this).html(txt)
    }
```

---

Finally you need to reset the `li` variable when creating the options

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/b0rspd5e/

Answer (score 1):

This solve part of the problem(the lowercase one plus useless highlight span) [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tkjarLes/5/):

```
highlight: function (val) {
    var nn = new RegExp('(' + val + ')', 'gi'),
         txt = $(this).find('label').text();
    if (val.replace(/\s/g, '') == '') {
        txt = txt.replace(new RegExp("<span class='highlight'>([\s\S]*?)</span>"),'$1');
        $('label', this).html(txt);
    }
    else{
    txt = txt.replace(nn, "<span class='highlight'>" + '$1' + "</span>");
    $('label', this).html(txt)
    }
}
```

Basically I have added the `()` to the `regex` to capture the group and then `'$1'` to subsitute the matched value.

**EDIT**
[FIDDLE VERSION 2](http://jsfiddle.net/tkjarLes/7/)
Done also the other problem(`match` way as suggested by Gaby aka G. Petrioli), it took me a while due to the returned value.
 
Basically if the string doesn't return any match the `var` is `null`, so `if(nMatch)` is enough.
It returns `true` if the `var` isn't `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `empty string ("")`, `0` or `false`

```
searchItem: function () {
    var patt = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi')
    var val = this.value;

    $('#options li').each(function () {
        var nMatch= $(this).text().match(patt);
        if(nMatch){
                $(this).show();
                apply.highlight.call(this, val)
        }
        else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })

    $('#options h2').each(function () {
         var nMatch= $('label', this).text().match(patt);
         if(nMatch){
                $(this).show();
                apply.highlight.call(this, val)
        }
        else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatedly calling the [`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method on the same regular expression which was created with `g` flag. When you do that, subsequent `.test`ing continues from the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex). Here is the matching process for the string `a`:

```
lastIndex    String              Substring to match    test() returns    Position
---------    ----------------    ------------------    --------------    --------
        0    " Volvo"            " Volvo"              false
        0    " Saab"             " Saab"               true                     2
        3    " Volvo"            "lvo"                 false
        0    " Saab"             " Saab"               true                     2
        3    " Mercedes"         "rcedes"              false
        0    " Audi"             " Audi"               true                     1
        2    " All Resident"     "ll Resident"         false
        0    " All Comercial"    " All Comercial"      true                     1
```

This explains why **"All Resident"** header is not shown. The solution is to remove the `g` flag since you want to test each string only once.

Comment: Thanks, I that is best explanation of an answer I have ever seen