# Regex'es weird behavior when doing Regex.exec(testString)

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

May I know why the following weird behavior happening for the below statements?

```
a = /\d+/gi
outputs `/\d+/gi`
a.exec('test1323')
outputs `["1323"]`
```

and again running the same statements gives
    a.exec('test1323')

> null

Even I tried creating regex using new Regex("regex string"), but still no change.

Please see the attachment[image]

It happens in chrome console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a regexp with the `g` flag. When you do that, the [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method remembers the position of the last match and matching starts from the last match. The results are explained below:

```
> a = /\d+/gi
< /\d+/gi  // a.lastIndex is initialized to 0
> a.exec("test1323")
< ["1323"] // match begins at 0, match found at index 4...7, a.lastIndex is now 8
> a.exec("test1323")
< null     // match begins at 8, no match found, a.lastIndex is reset to 0
> a.exec("test1323")
< ["1323"] // match begins at 0, match found at index 4...7, a.lastIndex is now 8
```

A longer dry run of similar problem [can be found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27860835/87015).